# Pull ~4000 images from subreddit with PRAW

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science, reddit, praw

I have a data science project where I'm trying to pull images from reddit with the associated upvotes on their post. I want to get around 3,000-4,000 samples.

PRAW only supports pulling 1,000 submissions at a time, and I'm struggling to find a way to start at the 1,000 new posts and then go back in 1,000 batches until I have enough.

Here is the code I'm currently trying to run:

```
download_sub = reddit.subreddit(sub_name)

MAX_POSTS = 4000  # Maximum number of posts to download
post_count = 0    # Counter for number of posts downloaded

# get the latest 1000 posts in the subreddit
latest_posts = download_sub.new(limit=1000)
#latest_posts = list(download_sub.new(limit=1000))


# create an empty dataframe with the specified columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id','PostedAt', 'Link', 'Username', 'Upvotes'])

for post in latest_posts:
   # get the post creation time in UTC and convert it to a datetime object
    utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(post.created_utc, timezone.utc)
    created_at = utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # get the post link, username, image link (if exists), and upvotes
    link = f"https://www.reddit.com{post.permalink}"
    username = post.author.name if post.author else '[deleted]'
    upvotes = post.score

    # if the post is a gallery, download the gallery, else download the image    

    if hasattr(post, "is_gallery"):
        df_filename = downloadGallery(post)
        df = df.append({'Id': post.id,
                    'PostedAt': created_at,
                    'Link': link,
                    'Username': username,
                    'Filename': df_filename,
                    'Upvotes': upvotes}, ignore_index=True)
    
    elif '.png' in post.url or '.jpg' in post.url or '.jpeg' in post.url:  
        df_filename = downloadImg(post)
        df = df.append({'Id': post.id,
                'PostedAt': created_at,
                'Link': link,
                'Username': username,
                'Filename': df_filename,
                'Upvotes': upvotes}, ignore_index=True)
        
    os.system('clear')
    post_count += 1
    oldest_post_id = post.id
    print(post_count, " done so far.")
    if post_count >= MAX_POSTS:
        break


# get the next 1000 posts before the oldest post in the latest 1000 posts
next_posts = download_sub.new(limit=1000, before=oldest_post_id)

# loop to get the next 1000 posts in batches until you reach MAX_POSTS

while len(next_posts) > 0:
    for post in next_posts:
         # get the post creation time in UTC and convert it to a datetime object
        utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(post.created_utc, timezone.utc)
        created_at = utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        # get the post link, username, image link (if exists), and upvotes
        link = f"https://www.reddit.com{post.permalink}"
        username = post.author.name if post.author else '[deleted]'
        upvotes = post.score
        
        # if the post is a gallery, download the gallery, else download the image
        
        if hasattr(post, "is_gallery"):
             df_filename = downloadGallery(post)
             df = df.append({'Id': post.id,
                    'PostedAt': created_at,
                    'Link': link,
                    'Username': username,
                    'Filename': df_filename,
                    'Upvotes': upvotes}, ignore_index=True)

        elif '.png' in post.url or '.jpg' in post.url or '.jpeg' in post.url:  
            df_filename = downloadImg(post)
            df = df.append({'Id': post.id,
                'PostedAt': created_at,
                'Link': link,
                'Username': username,
                'Filename': df_filename,
                'Upvotes': upvotes}, ignore_index=True)
            
        os.system('clear')
        post_count += 1
        oldest_post_id = post.id
        print(post_count, " done so far.")
        if post_count >= MAX_POSTS:
            break
        
    if post_count >= MAX_POSTS:
        break
        
    
    # get the next 1000 posts before the oldest post in the next 1000 posts
    next_posts = download_sub.new(limit=1000, before=oldest_post_id)
```

The thing is, the 'before=' parameter for subreddit.new() doesn't exist :) ChatGPT totally imagined that it did! Is there any way to accomplish something similar?

Thanks so much!

- Tried to pull 4,000 images and their metadata from reddit using PRAW, 1,000 posts at a time
- Couldn't find a way to 'stagger' the API to pull multiple batches of 1,000 one after the other

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, don't just post code from Chat GPT and expect us to fix it.